# Avoid passing around a context when making LINQ SQL OO?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Right now I'm making convenience classes that use LINQ.

Ex:

```
    public static bool Remove(Customer c,KezberPMDBDataContext context)
    {
        if (c != null && context != null)
        {
            KezberPMDBDataContext db = context;
            db.Customers.DeleteOnSubmit(c);
            db.SubmitChanges();
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

I have other functions like this:

```
public static Customer Get(string description,
            KezberPMDBDataContext context = null)
        {
            KezberPMDBDataContext db = GetContext(context);
            return (from p in db.Customers
                    where p.CustomerDescription == description
                    select p).FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

The problem is to do a task like removing a customer, I need the context.

Is there a way to do this without always needing to pass the context around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, create a new context for each of these operations.

Data contexts are not expensive to create.  The rely on connection pools so that each new context doesn't have the overhead of creating new connections.  Unless you have a compelling reason to back the operations that you're submitting, you probably are better off not passing around the contexts.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but if I Get a customer with 1 context then Remove him with another, it will fail.

Comment: Ex, if I have a method that returns a Customer, the Customer object is bount to the context it was gotten with.

Comment: @Milo Well, if it were me I'd just make both of these methods extension methods of the context, rather than nebulous static methods floating around, so you get the context as the implicit parameter.

Comment: I have several classes that need this, wont it get messy?

Comment: @Milo Doesn't the type that represents `db.Customers` have a reference back to the context?  Put the extension on that.